# Full height background image with scrolling content % or vh

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set a background image to fill the entire height and width of my screen (minus the header).  I have achieved that with the following styles:

```
    <div
      className={style.app}
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${HomePhoto})`,
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
        backgroundPosition: "0 4rem",
      }}
    >
```

CSS

```
.app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

The issue I have is when `height: 100%` the background image only fills the entire screen height if there is enough content to fill the screen. In other words the size of the background image depends on how much content is on the screen.

I can fix that by using `height: 100vh` however when I do this the content on the page will not scroll if it exceeds the page height.

How can I have a fixed background image that always fills the screen height and also allows content to scroll on top?

Comment: use `min-height: 100vh;` instead of `height: 100vh;`

Comment: Maybe `background-size: cover` is what you're looking for?

Comment: Can we have a working example via a code snippet? That could help us better understand what exactly you are looking for.